# Parent MOC get changes with empty data from child MOC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm stuck on this problem with CoreData and Parent-Child MOCs: when adding objects to child MOC, saving them and saving the parent MOC all the objects gets their attributes reset to defaultValue.

I pasted here the logs from the two MOCs, specifically are the "stringAttribute" and "date" attributes that in these log are reset.

I searched for this problem everywhere but i didn't find anything, I also looked at lots of implementation of Parent-Child MOCs but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code snippets:

I add some NSManagedObject to the main context and then save with `saveContext:` method

```
// Another singleton method
- (void)anotherMethod
{
   [...]
   [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:managedObject];
   NSError *error;
   save = [self saveContext:&error];
   [...]
}

// Database manager singleton method

- (BOOL)saveContext:(DKError *__autoreleasing *)error
{

    __block BOOL save = NO;
    __block NSError *internalError;

    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        internalError = nil;

        [self.managedObjectContext log]; // See log 1.1 below

        save = [self.managedObjectContext save:&internalError];
        if (!save) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving data in main context");
        } else {

            [self.managedObjectContext.parentContext performBlock:^{
                internalError = nil;
                save = NO;

                [self.managedObjectContext.parentContext log]; // See log 1.2 below

                save = [self.managedObjectContext.parentContext save:&internalError];
                if (!save) {
                    NSLog(@"Error saving data to disk!");
                }
            }];

        }
    }];
    *error = [DKError errorWithNSError:internalError]; // Custom error class
    return save;
}
```

Parent - Child contexts code

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)writerObjectContext
{
    if (_writerObjectContext != nil)
        return _writerObjectContext;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _writerObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_writerObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _writerObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setParentContext:[self writerObjectContext]];

    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Log 1.1

```
Inserted objects:
{(
    <Entity: 0x9595120> (entity: Entity; id: 0x9582d40 <x-coredata:///Entity/t24D0F98B-CB94-41D3-BEDD-79913454A9152> ; data: {
    [...]
    dateAttribute = "2013-07-12 10:36:31 +0000";
    stringAttribute = ricercaEntity;
    [...]
})
)}
```

Log 1.2

```
Inserted objects:
{(
    <Entity: 0xb53ce80> (entity: Entity; id: 0x9582d40 <x-coredata:///Entity/t24D0F98B-CB94-41D3-BEDD-79913454A9152> ; data: {
    [...]
    dateAttribute = "2013-01-05 11:00:00 +0000";
    stringAttribute = nil;
    [...]
})
)}
```

**UPDATE**

I've should have mention that the `managedObject` added to the context is initialized with context **nil**. Then before calling `saveContext:` I check for existence of `object.managedObjectContext` and if it's nil then I'll set that as `[self managedObjectContext]`, the one created with the method above. So either if the `managedObject` is created with nil context, or created with:

```
+ (id)newObjectForInsertion
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithEntity:[self entityDescription] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[DKDatabaseManager defaultManager].managedObjectContext];
}
```

the associated managedObjectContext is on the same queue (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType).

Otherwise if the `managedObject` is create with `+newObjectForInsertion` all of the `saveContext:` concurrency-chain return YES and all the changes are passed to parent context.

I don't know if it's a bug or the way CoreData should work.

Same problem on Apple Developer Forums:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/174677?tstart=90

Comment: Are you sure it's the same entity in the log? dateAttribute is not reset, but completely different.

Comment: Yes. It should be the same because the id passed is the same (`entity: Entity; id: 0x9582d40`). The date attribute is reset to the default value set in the .xcdatamodeld. The change should be passed safely using the `performBlockAndWait:` so i don't think is an issue with objectID. I'm not completely sure BTW

Answer (score 1):

You should init context with concurrencyType:

```
context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Also, set merge policy

```
[context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
```

> > NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
>
> This policy merges conflicts between the persistent store’s version of
>   the object and the current in-memory version, giving priority to
>   in-memory changes. The merge occurs by individual property. For
>   properties that have been changed in both the external source and in
>   memory, the in-memory changes trump the external ones.

Btw, I found similar question: [strange-behavior-when-using-child-parent-nsmanagedobjectcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222348/strange-behavior-when-using-child-parent-nsmanagedobjectcontext) look at the accepted answer which uses notifications to merge.

Comment: As you see, both contexts are init with concurrencyType, the writer one with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and the main one with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. I just tried to set the merge policy on the writer context but nothing's changed. I looked at link, but one solution do the same thing I do (setting the background as parent), the other one uses the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` that to my understanding should be used with 'old-before-5.0' parent-child pattern.